# Finding a vector parametric equation given a point and a perpendicular line in 2D

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametric

I've done similar questions in 3D, but can't figure out how to solve this 2D problem:

Give a two dimensional vector parametric equation for the line through the point $(0, -5)$ that is perpendicular to the line $\langle 5 + 5 t, 4 - t \rangle $

I started off by finding a vector perpendicular to <5, -1> and came up with <1, 5> I then filled in the equation: L(t) = (0 + 1t)i + (-5 + 5t)j but I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Please do not have links to images, instead attach the image itself. Also please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Try writing your answer as $\langle t , -5 + 5 t \rangle $